# VS2010 Intellisense disabling itself randomly, ReSharper installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010 Version 4.0.30319 and programming in C#.

I have ReSharper 6.1 installed as well.

Everything on my computer is up-to-date.

Here are my system specifications if needed:

> Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601)
>
> Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506)
>
> System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
>
> System Model: Inspiron N5030
>
> BIOS: Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A02
>
> Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU       T4500  @ 2.30GHz (2 CPUs),
>   ~2.3GHz
>
> Memory: 3072MB RAM
>
> Available OS Memory: 3034MB RAM

The problem I am having, and I believe it has to do with ReSharper, is that my intellisense keeps getting disabled seemingly randomly, and it's very annoying having to reenable it.

Is there a fix for this or will I have to just sit and wait patiently? I have searched the forums for a solution and google'd away but found no clear answers.

**edit**

Solved I believe. Looked under ReSharper > Options > Intellisense > General and set it to VS controlled rather than letting ReSharper have control.

Crossing my fingers and hoping this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4):

There are conflicts between Resharper and Visual Studio intellisense. You can fix this issue by simply allowing Visual Studio to reclaim its rights to Intellisense over Resharper by taking the following steps :

1. With Visual Studio, Select **Tools** from the main menu.
2. Select **Options** to be presented with the Options dialog box.
3. Find and Select the **Text Editor** section on the left-hand side.
4. Choose C# (or the language that you want Visual Studio to take over)
   beneath the Text Editor section.
5. Select the **General** category found under your chosen language.
6. On the right-hand side, you should **check** the **Auto list Members** and
   **Parameter information** checkboxes.

If you don’t notice the changes taking effect after performing these steps, simply restart your instance of Visual Studio. After restarting, you should find that Visual Studio has now assumed all of the Intellisense duties from Resharper and your Intellisense should be working as intended.

Source : http://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/a-battle-of-intellisense/

Comment: surprisingly, even in VS2015 this is still a thing

Comment: @GeorgeMauer This answer doesn't work. It will just stop working again in a few minutes. You need to actually disable resharper intellisense and use VS instead (as outlined at the bottom of the original question).... OR try a different solution to fix the real issue (resharper intellisense isn't working)

Comment: It worked for me, several weeks and counting. Did your VS crash maybe @Ravendarksky and didn't get the chance to save options on exit?

Comment: Whatever bug I currently have with resharper is resetting the setting every couple of minutes. Currently I've just disabled resharper intellisense entirely until I find a fix. The last three times this has happened over the years I've cleared out my local Resharper Cache as a fix, but no luck this time.

Comment: I did post this answer in 2013, Resharper and VS probably changed a lot.